# C Preprocessor concept

Tags: c

Can any one tell where exactly the macros are stored in memory? For example if I define a function some memory location will be allocated?
How will the preprocessing be done ?

Answer (score 4):

The preprocessor is just a text file parsing and substitution done before compiling.  So it doesn't have anything to do with memory.  It's like doing a copy/paste with your `#define`s and `#include`s into an expanded C file, then compiling that.

Answer (score 2):

Memory for a macro is stored only in the compiler's memory. Yes, it is memory that gets allocated, but not by your application. The only impact it has on your application is where you use the macro, where code gets added to your application.

Memory for a function is quite different, yet you asked about them both as though they go together. Perhaps you can clarify the information you are looking for.